# Unable to run command chsh -s /bin/bash ${USERNAME}

Tags: linux, docker, unix, sed, debian

I have a docker file where I have customized image myimage derived from some-debian-image (which derived from debian upstream.)

```
FROM some-debian-image myimge  

USERNAME root:root
...........................
RUN chsh -s /bin/bash ${USERNAME}
```

docker build fails saying :

```
Password: chsh: PAM: Authentication failure
```

However, it does not fail with upstream

```
FROM bebain:bullseye myimage

USERNAME root:root
...........................
RUN chsh -s /bin/bash ${USERNAME}
```

Developers who have build the some-debian-image have done something add on with /etc/passwd , and it is having content

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

May I please know how to successfully run this command :

```
RUN chsh -s /bin/bash ${USERNAME}
```

I  am comparing docker images setup where it is working and where it is not working , and I found that:

The setup where the above command  `RUN chsh -s /bin/bash ${USERNAME}` is working `sudo su` can be expected without any password

```
$ sudo su
#
```

In contrast in setup where I am facing issue ask for password when run the command `sudo su`

May I pleas know what changes I should do so that  `sudo su` shall not ask for password?

Comment: Because it's a PAM failure, if you want to fix it properly, you'd need to review the PAM configuration for the specific Docker image you're running that command in

Comment: By contrast, to fix it _improperly_, you can just edit `/etc/passwd` directly.

Comment: What is the single process you expect the container to run; what application are you packaging in the image?  I would usually expect that to be some program (Tomcat, Nginx, PostgreSQL, your local microservice, ...) and not an interactive shell; you shouldn't normally need to `chsh` or otherwise do things to "set up a user".

Comment: Did you check the logs? Usually they have more informations. Maybe it is just that you should give `root` as user (not `root:root`). Or some missconfiguration. Check the logs!